# What happen in DELETE on an entity node of a list in JPA?

Tags: jpa, entitymanager

Correct me If Im wrong.

```
public class Person{
  List<Cars> myCars;
  //Get and Set
}

public class Car{
  Here Attribs    
}
```

If Car car is member of myCars, and i delete em.remove(car); it also removes it from the list mycars. SQLed say: does it remove the asociation PERSON_CAR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if there are some implementation specific configurations that support what you are trying, but normally if you do `em.remove(car)`, the `List<Cars>` will **not** be updated. You either have to remove the `Car` entity from the list yourself or refresh the person entity after the remove operation is committed.